# How to get signInAnonymously from AngularFireAuth to return a promise

Tags: angular, firebase, promise, async-await, angularfire

I've been following fireship.io's tutorial for setting up stripe payments.
In [their repo's auth service](https://github.com/fireship-io/171-stripe-elements-angular/blob/master/src/app/services/auth.service.ts), I'm seeing a lot of conversions of observables to promises, presumably to allow for the very useful and readable async/await syntax in the checkout component.
For instance, this method exists in the auth service:

```
getUser(): Promise<any> {
    return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(first()).toPromise();
  }
```

allowing for a call like this in the component

```
const user = await this.auth.getUser();
```

I'm trying to essentially allow users to make a donation to my webapp, which doesn't require any login whatsoever. Currently, I have a call to stripeCreateCharge in my checkout component (see below), but it depends on the `auth.getUser()` method, which I think means I need some kind of login.

So, I created an anonymous login method in the auth service, and call it upstream of the handler call.

From auth.service.ts:

```
anonymousLogin() {
    console.log("anonymousLogin entered");
    // console.log('AuthIsStateResolved: ' + this.afAuth.auth.isStateResolved_);
    this.afAuth.auth.signInAnonymously()
     .then((credential) => {
       console.log("success inside callback for signInAnonymously");
       console.log(credential.user);
       // this.authState = credential;
       this.updateUserData(credential.user);
       return this.getUser();
     })
     .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

In my checkout.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.signOut();
    this.handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'pk_live_ztqhLfPwjEf2SFC26LDmWkXr',
      locale: 'auto',
      source: async (source) => {
        this.displayThings = true;
        this.loading = true;
        console.log("got into source callback from handler in checkout.component");
        this.auth.anonymousLogin();
        const user = await this.auth.getUser();
        console.log(user);
        if(user){
          const fun = this.functions.httpsCallable('stripeCreateCharge');
          this.confirmation = await fun({ source: source.id, uid: user.uid, amount: this.amount }).toPromise();
          console.log("this.confirmation");
          console.log(this.confirmation.outcome.seller_message);
          this.loading = false;
          if(this.confirmation.outcome.seller_message === "Payment complete."){
            this.paymentStatus = this.confirmation.outcome.seller_message + " Thank you!";
          } else{
            this.paymentStatus = this.confirmation.outcome.seller_message;
          }
        } else{
          console.log("ack never happened");
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Paying special attention to the lines

```
        this.auth.anonymousLogin();
        const user = await this.auth.getUser();
        console.log(user);
```

above, I'm seeing that `this.auth.anonymousLogin()` doesn't complete until *after* `const user = await this.auth.getUser();` gets called, so we have an asynchronicity issue, as evidenced by the console output:

[image]

My question: is there a way I can modify anonymousLogin() to return a promise when it's done, so that I can continue using the async/await syntax, and have something like,

```
        const loggedInStatus = await this.auth.anonymousLogin();
        if(loggedInStatus){
            const user = await this.auth.getUser();
            console.log(user);
            // More stuff in here...
        }
```

Alternatively, is there better advice for how to handle this whole thing?

**Update 17 December, 2019:**

When I add return to my signInAnonymously method, it returns **undefined** in my checkout.component.ts:

auth.service.ts

```
...
anonymousLogin() {
    console.log("anonymousLogin entered");
    // console.log('AuthIsStateResolved: ' + this.afAuth.auth.isStateResolved_);
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInAnonymously()
     .then((credential) => {
       console.log("success inside callback for signInAnonymously");
       console.log(credential.user);
       // this.authState = credential;
       this.updateUserData(credential.user);
       // return this.getUser();
     })
     .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

checkout.component.ts

```
...
const loggedInStatus = await this.auth.anonymousLogin();
        console.log("test user");
        console.log(loggedInStatus);
        const user = await this.auth.getUser();
        console.log(loggedInStatus);
        //below not updated yet
        if(user){
          const fun = this.functions.httpsCallable('stripeCreateCharge');
          this.confirmation = await fun({ source: source.id, uid: user.uid, amount: this.amount }).toPromise();
          console.log("this.confirmation");
          console.log(this.confirmation.outcome.seller_message);
          this.loading = false;
          if(this.confirmation.outcome.seller_message === "Payment complete."){
            this.paymentStatus = this.confirmation.outcome.seller_message + " Thank you!";
          } else{
            this.paymentStatus = this.confirmation.outcome.seller_message;
          }
        } else{
          console.log("ack never happened");
        }
...
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to add `return` to your `anonymousLogin` method?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `return this.afAuth.auth.signInAnonymously().then....`

Comment: Interesting. When I do that and then await it within my checkout component (`const user = await this.auth.anonymousLogin();`) and log it in the console, it is undefined!

Comment: That's because you commented `// return this.getUser();` If you use `Promise.then` and want the Promise returns something you should return something in `then` statement. It can be either any value or another Promise

Comment: @yurzui thanks for your continued effort to help! You're right - that does fix it! Forgive me for being so new to this! I hadn't realized that you could have kind of nested return statements like that in Promise.then() chains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a proper Promise chain you need to:

- return a Promise
- pass the result through the chain of .then handlers

So your code should be like:

```
anonymousLogin() {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInAnonymously()
    ^^^^^^
   add this

     .then((credential) => {
       return this.getUser();
      ^^^^^^
 return smth in then callback
     })
     ...
}
```